# How to reload data in ZK PivotTable with new values when combobox onchange event trigger

Tags: combobox, zk, zul

I need to reload data in ZK pivot table when ombobox onchange  event trigger.

If user change the value from the comobox { as shown in below code } data should change based on user selection.

index.zul

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.pivot.demo.PivotDemoBaseController"  >
    <hlayout>
        <panel id="main" hflex="1" border="normal">
            <caption label="2012 Data">
                <toolbarbutton id="exportCsvBtn" label="Export CSV"  />
                <toolbarbutton id="exportXlsBtn" label="Export XLS" />
                <toolbarbutton id="exportXlsxBtn" label="Export XLSX" />
            </caption>
            <panelchildren>
                <vlayout spacing="0">
                    <pivottable id="pivot" hflex="1" pageSize="15"  >





                        <combobox model="${lm}"  id="selectGeo"/>
                        <div>All People</div>
                    </pivottable>
                    <div id="descDiv" />
                </vlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
        <panel id="field" title="Control" width="300px" border="normal"  >
            <panelchildren>
                <vlayout style="padding: 10px">
                    <!-- Predefined scenario: -->
                    <hlayout id="preDef" spacing="0"  />
                    <div class="footnote" style="padding: 5px 0">(Drag fields among the areas below)</div>
                    <pivot-field-control id="pfc" height="300px" />
                    <hlayout hflex="1">
                        <checkbox id="autoUpdate" label="Auto Update" checked="true" />
                        <div hflex="1" />
                        <!-- <button id="updateBtn" label="Update" disabled="true" autodisable="+self" /> -->
                    </hlayout>
                    <separator />
                    <checkbox id="colGrandTotal" label="Enable grand total for columns" />
                    <checkbox id="rowGrandTotal" label="Enable grand total for rows" />
                    <div>
                        <radiogroup id="dataOrient">
                            Data field orientation:
                            <radio id="colOrient" label="column" />
                            <radio id="rowOrient" label="row" />
                        </radiogroup>
                    </div>
                </vlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </hlayout>
</window>
```

Below is the code of my Controller

public class PivotDemoBaseController extends SelectorComposer {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7531153593366258488L;

private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { "(Data Title)", "(Column Title)", "(Row Title)" };


@Wire
private Pivottable pivot;

@Wire
private PivotFieldControl pfc;

@Wire
private Button updateBtn;

@Wire
private Checkbox colGrandTotal, rowGrandTotal;

@Wire
private Radio colOrient, rowOrient;

@Wire
private Hlayout preDef;

@Wire
private Div descDiv;

private TabularPivotModel _model;

@Wire
private Combobox selectGeo;




private CellStyleConfigurator styleConfigurator;

public void onCheck$autoUpdate(CheckEvent event) {
    boolean deferred = !event.isChecked();
    pfc.setDeferredUpdate(deferred);
    if (!deferred)
        updateBtn.setDisabled(true);
}


@Listen("onChange = #selectGeo")
public void onChangeSelectGeo(Event event) {        
     String geography = selectGeo.getValue();
   System.out.println("Value---"+geography);

}

public void onClick$updateBtn() {
    pfc.update();
}

public void onPivotFieldControlChange$pfc() {
    if (!pfc.isUpdated())
        updateBtn.setDisabled(false);
}

public void onCheck$colGrandTotal(CheckEvent event) {
    System.out.println("PivotDemoBaseController.onCheck$colGrandTotal()");
    pivot.setGrandTotalForColumns(event.isChecked());
}

public void onCheck$rowGrandTotal(CheckEvent event) {
    pivot.setGrandTotalForRows(event.isChecked());
}

public void onCheck$dataOrient(CheckEvent event) {
    pivot.setDataFieldOrient(((Radio)event.getTarget()).getLabel());
}

public void onClick$exportCsvBtn() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PivotExportContext context = Exports.getExportContext(pivot, true, TITLES);
    Exports.exportCSV(out, context);
    Filedownload.save(out.toByteArray(), "text/csv", "pivot.csv");
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void onClick$exportXlsBtn() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PivotExportContext context = Exports.getExportContext(pivot, true, TITLES);
    Exports.exportExcel(out, "xls", context, styleConfigurator);
    Filedownload.save(out.toByteArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "pivot.xls");
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void onClick$exportXlsxBtn() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PivotExportContext context = Exports.getExportContext(pivot, true, TITLES);
    Exports.exportExcel(out, "xlsx", context, styleConfigurator);
    Filedownload.save(out.toByteArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "pivot.xlsx");
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

@NotifyChange("*")
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("PivotDemoBaseController.doAfterCompose()");
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    StaticPivotModelFactory pmf = StaticPivotModelFactory.INSTANCE;

    //PivotModelFactory pmf= (PivotModelFactory) arg.get("factory");
    _model = pmf.build();
    pivot.setModel(_model);
    pfc.setModel(_model);
    Executions.createComponents(pmf.getDescriptionURI(), descDiv, null);

    loadConfiguration(pmf.getDefaultConfigurator());

    // load predefined scenario
    for(PivotConfigurator conf : pmf.getConfigurators())
        preDef.appendChild(getPreDefDiv(conf));
}

private void initControls() {
    System.out.println("PivotDemoBaseController.initControls()");
    // grand totals
    colGrandTotal.setChecked(pivot.isGrandTotalForColumns());
    rowGrandTotal.setChecked(pivot.isGrandTotalForRows());

    // data orientation
    ("column".equals(pivot.getDataFieldOrient()) ? 
            colOrient : rowOrient).setChecked(true);

    pfc.syncModel(); // field control
}

private Component getPreDefDiv(final PivotConfigurator conf) {
    Div div = new Div();
    div.setHflex("1");
    div.setSclass("predef");
    div.appendChild(new Label(conf.getTitle()));
    div.addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener(){
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            loadConfiguration(conf);
        }
    });
    return div;
}

private void loadConfiguration(PivotConfigurator conf) {
    System.out.println("PivotDemoBaseController.loadConfiguration()");
    _model.clearAllFields(true);
    conf.configure(_model);
    conf.configure(pivot);
    pivot.setPivotRenderer(conf.getRenderer());
    styleConfigurator = conf.getCellStyleConfigurator();
    initControls();
}
```

}

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see onChange event handler for comobobox is not doing anything except print selected value. If you want to update pivottable all you need to do is prepare a new model and call setModel() API on it.

Comment: Thanks for reply...i tried with  NotifyChange("yourModelObject")  but it doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: Either go with MVC (setModel() on pivottable) or MVVM (NotifyChange annotation on the method that updates the model). I'm not sure what you tried with NotifyChange and "it doesn't seem to work for me" does not give us any hint. Help us help you by providing specific details. In general I would suggest improve on the above code that already uses MVC instead of changing to MVVM as MVVM does have a bit of learning curve if you are a beginner with ZK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean the [@NotifyChange](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Syntax/ViewModel/@NotifyChange) annotation, but it is for MVVM data-binding, which you did not use.
You can switch to the [MVVM data binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM) or you schould update it like this:

```
@Listen("onChange = #selectGeo")
public void onChangeSelectGeo(CheckEvent event) {
    // Manipulate pivot element here.
}
```

For more info, see [CheckEvent](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/CheckEvent.html) and [MVVM vs MVC](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/December/MVVM_in_ZK6%3ain_Contrast_to_MVC).